# AS#3 Game Development

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, cs4

For some time i have been making more or less little games. One level generally, These become incomplete cause they annoy the crap out of me at times, I get an idea than find it hard to implement.Consistantly just run from one problem to the next.

Anyways  my latest quest is an isometric game, like simcity or something along them lines
My question is should i been learning these free librarys for instance ISOLIBS to complete this task?

Iv always been hesitent to use extended librarys as i want to create my own base engines, i would assume I would have better control and understanding.As of most the time i have been daizing at a google page trying to think of ways to structure my apps.

This is more of a trivial question, but im after a trivial answer that may direct me to a more proffesional approach, for instance other library's or personal , comercial opinions.
Please keep in mind i think i am confident in programming but i havent had no formal experience at all so this is my classroom.

Thanks

Comment: using libraries doesnt mean using black boxes , most of them are open source , nobody forbids you from looking at the source code.

Comment: i want to know if using library's a cop out from actually learning actionScript thoroughly.thanks for you comment

Comment: do you think reading other's people code prevent you from learning a langage ?quite the contrary.

Comment: No not all, breaking it down 1+1 = 2 working out i would think be more beneficial then using a calculater, most of everything iv learned i had read from adobe docs and other source codes its only recent times where i ponder more to reach my own theory or answers than googling answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a project as a whole will definitely give you a feeling of a daunting task ahead.

Well the scenario is similar if you are going to start with any project.

So, nothing really special to AS3 here. But here are my 2 cents:

- Since you are learning, don't even expect the commercial side of your
  project before hand.
- Pick up a project & stick to it. Make sure never start anything else 
  in parallel.
- Don't decide to use any library upfront.
- Break your project into smallest of parts & pick only one part at a time.
- Start it. Simply start the first sub problem... one after the other.
- Decide to use a library for a problem only if you have atleast
  theoretically dealt with the problem & don't wish to spend time
  writing it.

Maybe or maybe not you get a game out of this one, but the next time you surely will.

Comment: thank you i appreciate the two cents, flash for me is a hobby and if i had finish school im sure i would have progressed further than what i have over the last 4 years, my learning curve was the structure of programming, I didnt have any one to explain nothing at all, Stay in school kids